# gke backend services in UNHEALTHY state when liveness and readiness probe is of type exec and healthcheck url required authentication

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to configure the application in the GKE cluster.

**current situation**

- my application is using authenticated health checks.
- to handle this I am using `exec` instead of `httpGet`. it enables me to use curl with
  authentication details (with HTTP get it is providing 401 (unauthorized error))
- when I execute the helm chart I can see

  - pod is in a ready state with container 1/1 (earlier it was showing me (with HTTP get) as 0/1 )

**code**
exec code for readiness and liveness probe.

```
exec [bash -c curl -G --fail --silent --show-error -u $AUTH_ADMIN_USERNAME:$AUTH_ADMIN_PASSWORD localhost:$PORT/actuator/health] delay=60s timeout=10s period=30s #success=1 #failure=8
```

**expected**
this backend service (with readiness and liveness probe) in a healthy state

Comment: What version of kubernetes did you use? Is your endpoind enabled and exposed? Please add this info to the question.

Comment: i am using k8s version v1.18.17-gke.1901 . this actuator url require credentials for healthcheck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having problem during authorizing your request. For example, on a server with token authentication configured, and anonymous access enabled, a request providing an invalid bearer token would receive a `401 Unauthorized` error. You need to eliminate first the `401 error`.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authentication) you can find a guide, how to set up Kubelet authentication:

> By default, requests to the kubelet's HTTPS endpoint that are not rejected by other configured authentication methods are treated as anonymous requests, and given a username of  `system:anonymous`  and a group of  `system:unauthenticated`.
> To disable anonymous access and send  `401 Unauthorized`  responses to unauthenticated requests:
>
> - start the kubelet with the  `--anonymous-auth=false`  flag
>   To enable X509 client certificate authentication to the kubelet's HTTPS endpoint:
> - start the kubelet with the  `--client-ca-file`  flag, providing a CA bundle to verify client certificates with
> - start the apiserver with  `--kubelet-client-certificate`  and  `--kubelet-client-key`  flags
> - see the  [apiserver authentication documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs)  for more details
>   To enable API bearer tokens (including service account tokens) to be used to authenticate to the kubelet's HTTPS endpoint:
> - ensure the  `authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`  API group is enabled in the API server
> - start the kubelet with the  `--authentication-token-webhook`  and  `--kubeconfig`  flags
> - the kubelet calls the  `TokenReview`  API on the configured API server to determine user information from bearer tokens

You can find also a guide about [Kubelet authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authorization):

> There are many possible reasons to subdivide access to the kubelet API:
>
> - anonymous auth is enabled, but anonymous users' ability to call the kubelet API should be limited
> - bearer token auth is enabled, but arbitrary API users' (like service accounts) ability to call the kubelet API should be limited
> - client certificate auth is enabled, but only some of the client certificates signed by the configured CA should be allowed to use the kubelet API

---

See also:

- [Guide on how to create liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)
- [Define a liveness HTTP request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request)